# Is a teacher allowed to talk the press about a former high school student?

Tags: united-states

Like let's say a student graduates and few years later is accused of a crime.  Like a hate crime maybe. Could a former teacher tell the press about the subjects of various papers that the student chose to write? Say things like, "he idolized hitler and held white supremacist views?"

Comment: Interesting question. FERPA only protects PII and their education record, not the work itself (e.g. the grade on the assignment is recorded as part of the record, but the entire assignment text is not recorded as part of the record), from being disclosed. I'm not sure if there are other laws that protect the disclosure of the work itself. School district policies usually cover this kind of stuff anyways, for a variety of ethical reasons (though if they don't work for that school district anymore, they might not care).